# Meaning of specific SPI transaction

Tags: raspberry-pi, spi, hex

I am working with someone else's code, and I have a question about several of the SPI transactions that are performed. The hardware configuration consists of a Raspberry Pi (master) and a motor driver board (slave). They are using the `spidev` Python library. The code to initialize and configure the SPI connection proceeds as follows:

```
import spidev

bus = 0 # SPI bus (channel 0 for Pi)
device = 0 # Device / chip select

spi = spidev.SpiDev() # Enable SPI
spi.open(bus,device) # Open connection on bus to device

# Set SPI speed and mode
spi.max_speed_hz = SPI_freq
spi.mode = 1
```

Then, they use `xfer2()` to perform the SPI transactions.

```
spi.xfer2((0x28, 0x00, 0x01)) #0x280001
spi.xfer2((0x38, 0x00, 0x01)) #0x380001
spi.xfer2((0x20, 0x00, 0x0F)) #0x20000F
spi.xfer2((0x30, 0x00, 0x00)) #0x300000
```

My question is this: 1.) What is actually happening in this SPI transaction? and 2.) What is the purpose of splitting, say, `0x280001` into a tuple of three, like `(0x28, 0x00, 0x01)`?

Comment: Here you can find the SpiDev documentation: https://sigmdel.ca/michel/ha/rpi/dnld/draft_spidev_doc.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is happening is that the bytes are sent out as single SPI transaction on each line. The four lines send four transactions. What those transactions mean is up to the slave chip.
2. The SPI bus usually sends out bytes so it makes sense to define the sequence of bytes you want to send.